# CURL + Passing $_POST variables/array

Tags: php, jquery, curl

I have the following situation:

```
if(isset($_POST['thisvalue'])) {

$username = $_POST['username'];
$passwd = $_POST['passwd'];

$ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,            'http://www.domain.com/scripts/curl/index_general.php' );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST,           true );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,            'http://www.domain.com.au' );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     "body goes here" ); 
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER,     array('Content-Type: text/plain')); 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
```

I can the "http://www.domain.com/scripts/curl/index_general.php" to return a value.

I need to know the best way to complete the line:
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,     "body goes here" );

How should I send the username/passwd.
I will have other time when I need to send more data so I assume (and from my reading that an array is best)...

Currently my data is passed from JQUERY/HTML... how should I then convert this data into an array and the CURL it to the destination domain?

thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the best way (secure) method for passing username and password as HTTP HEADER AUTHENTICATION WITH CURL.

```
if(isset($_POST['thisvalue'])) {

$username = $_POST['username'];
$passwd = $_POST['passwd'];

$data = array('serialno' => '12345');    

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://www.domain.com/scripts/curl/index_general.php');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD,'username:password'); // set your username and password
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER,'http://www.domain.com.au');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: text/plain')); 
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $result;
}
```

In index_general.php

you can access the http username and password as

```
$_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_USER'] and $_SERVER['PHP_AUTH_PW']
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, array('username' => $_POST['username'], 'passwd' => $_POST['passwd']));
```

Comment: Worth noting: when `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS` is an array, the `Content-Type` will be `multipart/form-data`. In practice it probably makes no difference, but anyway.

Comment: Don't know about what your comment was but if you really don't want to send form as `mutipart/form-data` you can do like that:  `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query(array('username' => $_POST['username'], 'passwd' => $_POST['passwd'])));`

Comment: It was about "nothing", just a FYI. As I said, probably makes no difference in practice.

Answer (score 1):

Credential security aside, if you want a quick answer to the title topic of "CURL + Passing $_POST variables/array" and don't need to worry about sensitive data, you can try this:

```php
$post_fields = '';
foreach ( $_POST as $a => $b ) { $post_fields .= $a.'='.$b.'&'; }
$post_fields = substr( $post_fields, 0, -1 );

curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_fields );
```

Then you don't need to manually enumerate any possible POST fields.