# curl to php conversion, array + json

Tags: php, curl

I have this curl code i need to convert it to php

```
curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"command":"sendoffer", 
"steamID":"###############","token":"lkTR4VG2", "itemIDsToRequest":["4942877123","4892501549"],
"message": "Message"}' http://website:1337/
```

As you can see there is an array along with normal json.

```
"itemIDsToRequest":["4942877123","4892501549"]
```

I looked at many question  like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8572535/curl-passing-post-variables-array)  and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20318194/how-to-convert-a-command-line-curl-to-php-curl), but couldn't understand how to implement it.

Im sorry im very new to curl command.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the array is part of a JSON string that is not interpreted but used as plain string data in CURL so it does not really matter what is in there; use the very same JSON string as from your commandline example, so:

```
$data = '{"command":"sendoffer", "steamID":"###############","token":"lkTR4VG2", "itemIDsToRequest":["4942877123","4892501549"], "message": "Message"}'
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data );
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type: application/json'));
```

Comment: Yes he's right. No need to convert to a php array :D 
Why did i do it ?!

Comment: I answered the question strictly, but I'm sure the json_encode call is something that would part of the answer to his next question ;-)

Comment: @HansZandbelt im creating array dynamically .. so instead of creating array should i just create a string in that format

Comment: well if you have to assemble data dynamically, direct string manipulation is often more painful and error prone than managing an array and finally calling `json_encode` when you're ready to send it; just consider the string manipulation that you would have to do if you wanted to add a single item to your existing `$data` as opposed to adding it to an array

Answer (score 0):

If your array is

```
$data = array("command"=>"sendoffer", "steamID"=>"###############","token"=>"lkTR4VG2", "itemIDsToRequest"=>array("4942877123","4892501549"),"message"=>"Message");
```

Then send it on its way as json format with curl like that :

```
$url = 'http://website:1337/';
$ch = curl_init( $url );

// Convert array to json string
$data_json = json_encode( $data );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data_json );

// Indicate in the header that it is json data
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:application/json')); 

// Send request
$result = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```